# Multivariable and gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

How do you find a function $f(x,y,z)$ given its gradient $
\nabla f = \langle a(x,y,z) , b(x,y,z), c(x,y,z) \rangle
$. Should we just integrate each equation with respect to the different variables? In this case, with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$. How is that achieved?

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the method, I will give you two examples. Let's consider a rather simple case.

Find $f(x,y)$ given $\nabla f = \langle x^2, y^2\rangle $. To do this, notice that, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x^2$. We can simply integrate this and obtain $f(x,y) = \frac{x^3}{3}+g(y)$. Note the constant is $g(y)$. Now, we just have to find $g(y)$. To do so, let's differentiate $f(x,y)$ with respect to $y$. We get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=g'(y)= y^2$. Integrating with respect to $y$, we get $g(y)= \frac{y^3}{3}+c$. Hence, the function $f(x,y)$ is given by
$$
f(x,y)= \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{y^3}{3}+c
$$
where $c$ is some constant. In fact, you could say, we could just have integrated each part with respect to $x$ and $y$ and get the answer. Not always! Look at the example below.

Find $f(x,y)$ given that $\nabla f = \langle 3x^2y^2, 2x^3y+y^5 \rangle $. Repeating the above procedure, note that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3x^2y$. Integrating with respect to $x$, we obtain $f(x,y)=x^3y^{2}+g(y)$. Now differentiate this with respect to $y$. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2x^{3}y + g'(y)= 2x^{3}y+y^{5}$. Comparing both sides, we have $g'(y)=y^{5}$ which implies that $g(y)= \frac{y^6}{6}+c$. Hence, $f(x,y)$ is given by
$$
f(x,y)= x^3y^2+\frac{y^6}{6}+c
$$

Answer (score 1):

The usual method that is taught is alternating integration and differentiation, as in [felasfa’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1966234/265466). This can get tedious for functions of more than two variables. There’s another method that gets you an antiderivative of $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in two steps regardless of the number of variables.

1. In the expression $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)\cdot\langle dx_1,\dots,dx_n\rangle$ make the substitutions $x_k\to tx_k$ and $dx_k\to x_k\,dt$.
2. Integrate the result with respect to $t$ from $0$ to $1$.

For example, if $F(x,y)=\langle3x^2y^2,2x^3y+y^5\rangle$ we substitute into $3x^2y^2\,dx+(2x^3y+y^5)\,dy$: $$3(tx)^2(ty)^2x\,dt+(2(tx)^3(ty)+(ty)^5)y\,dt = (5x^3y^2t^4+y^6t^5)\,dt$$ and integrate: $$\int_0^1 5x^3y^2t^4+y^6t^5\,dt=x^3y^2+\frac16y^6.$$ We can find an antiderivative of $F(x,y,z)=\langle3x^2y^2-y^2e^z,2x^3y+y^5-2xye^z,-xy^2e^z\rangle$ as easily: $$\int_0^1 x(3(tx)^2(ty)^2-(ty)^2e^{tz})+y(2(tx)^3(ty)+(ty)^5-2(tx)(ty)e^{tz})-z((tx)(ty)^2e^{tz})\,dt  \\ = \int_0^1 t^5y^6+5t^4x^3y^2-(t^3z+3t^2)xy^2e^{tz}\,dt \\ =\frac16y^6+x^3y^2-xy^2e^z.$$

This method takes advantage of the fact that, if the curl-closed vector field $F:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is defined on a star-shaped region centered on the origin, then the function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ defined as $f(P)=\int_\Gamma F\cdot d\mathbf r$, where $\Gamma$ is a smooth path joining the origin to the point $P$, is an antiderivative of $F$. The line integral is computed along the line segment from the origin to $P$ using the obvious parameterization.